# Ironing out a design for resonant inductive coupling on 13A. Would I be better off with MHz or GHz for efficient power transfer?

Tags: resonance, inductive, wireless-charging

I am having a go at designing an extension cord that uses resonant inductive coupling.  My knowledge lacks in this area, so I'm going back and forth via online research & chatgpt 3.5.

From what I gather, higher frequencies allow for more efficient power transfer but it can also raise additional challenges and costs.

Ideally I want make a low cost extension cord that is power efficient for a 13 ampere circuit but also if I decided to put in a large volume order it is not going to break the bank to do so / charge a fortune to an end user.

With that being said, would I be better off with a resonant frequency in the MHz range or GHz range?

If so what would you say is an ideal range for me to aim for?

Edit:

Sorry, let me make better sense of the idea, I'm trying to design a modular power strip. Everything is modular including the socket (will house a receiving coil & inductor) & socket base (which will house a transmitting LC circuit), additionally I wanted to make it so that actual sockets had unlimited rotation.

I had originally looked at slip rings, realised they're too expensive for this application, so started looking into Resonant Inductive coupling, whereby you could insert any form of socket into the socket base, rotate it to how you want it (cable management) without fear of losing power.

The entire power strip socket base is also modular, so you could attach more bases think nano leaf but as a power strip.

I've already figured out I'll be having to use 14 AWG wire to achieve the current need.

Distance between the actual socket base and socket is planned to be only couple cm's at most.

So back to my original question, I'm looking for what frequency would be best for the short distance and achieve everything above I've stated.

Comment: An "extension cord" is a cable with connectors at each end.  It doesn't need MHz or GHz anything.  Wireless power transfer is not an extension cord.

Comment: Leave the chatbots out of things.  You'll find more information and more accurate information from reference works (books) than in crap the chatbots puke up.

Comment: Daft question but would the Art of Electronics by Horowitz/Hills cover this, I have the book to my right.

Comment: Do you have a cordless electric kettle at home? Look at its base connector. This is a free-rotating 13 A three pin connection that costs only a few dollars. If you look carefully inside you'll even find a part number. Your power electronics idea is a thousand dollar solution. It might be useful to transfer power to a fast-rotating machine (though carbon brushes have been around for two hundred years). It seems overkill if you just want occasional free rotation for your hairdryer or whatever.

Comment: @tomnexus thanks for the idea, will have a look into it.

Comment: @tomnexus this is perfect, and something I could definitely work with instead. Can't believe I didn't think of something so simple.

Comment: You're trying to make a $1 problem in to a $1000 problem. They do make plugs with rotating contacts. I've seen them on power strip cords made by Belkin.

Comment: Yeah I know, I've seen them too but what I don't see is that combined with modular sockets, that you can place similar to that of nanoleaf. I wanted to create modular power strip, that you could do just that.

For example say you have an wall socket on a far away wall, and you want to charge your phone from the sofa, in a freehold house you could just put another socket in, but in a leasehold you can't, my idea was you could had that modular aspect of some sockets on 1 side, you could then have a modular cable that attaches on the side, then you can place some more sockets on the other side.

Comment: Additionally, I also didn't want e-waste, which is what you see with a lot of people buying extension cords / power strips, they buy say a 4 socket one, then they expand the number of their appliances and have to buy say 8 socket one, now they have a 4 & 8 socket one, and if they out grew the 8 socket one, they may like me buy a 12 socket one. So then you have a plethora of power strips - 1x 12, 1x8 & 1x4.

With my idea you had an additional appliance, no problem just add another socket module on, and done & you wouldn't be limited by direction or amount.

Comment: Also those rotating contacts on belkin, those slip rings and are ridiculously expensive.

Comment: "what frequency would be best" For an extension cord? 50 or 60 Hz. "then you have a plethora of power strips" Sounds like a bonus, not a problem. I keep finding new uses for mine.

Comment: @GrahamNye aye more cords is great and everything, not so much if you don't have that much space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *From what I gather higher frequencies allow for more efficient power
> transfer*

No, that is not correct. At the higher frequencies (such as high VHF or UHF) it's more likely that you'll be transmitting a propagating EM wave and, only a fraction of that power will reach the receiver; the rest is lost.

With lower frequency near-field coupling, the energy wasted on generating an EM wave is much smaller (governed by physical dimensions) hence, because you will be receiving the near-field electric or magnetic fields (note that I didn't say EM fields), there is little energy lost.

> *would I be better off with an resonant frequency in the MHz range or
> GHz range?*

It totally depends on your application and requirements and, I'm not going to guess at those. But, I will say this; I'm quite happy with my designs that run sub-MHz but, like I said, my designs are aimed at a specific target application.

> *And if so what would you say is an ideal range for me to aim for?*

This cannot be answered.

> *Ideally I want make a low cost extension cord that is power efficient
> for a 13 ampere circuit*

This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Edited the main post to hopefully make more better sense of what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Dragonfly3r thank you for making your edit unambiguously clear. Nevertheless, you still have a mountain to climb in working out how to transmit several kW across an air-gap of a couple cm. I should point out that the VA (volts x amps) needed at the transmitter will be several fold what the VA is in the take-off point and, this is a major cause of concern in heat dissipation due to things never being 100% power efficient. You'll be lucky to get 50% power coupling efficiency for instance. So, 1 kW out might mean anything up to 1 kW in power dissipation as heat.

Comment: That was what I figured, might look into what @Tomnexus mentioned about electric kettle connector and how that works. There's a lot of work but if it works out, then it will be game changing.